# Increase performance of simple push pop "stack"

Tags: python, performance

I was asked to do an interview question on Hackerrank to implement a stack. One of the methods of the stack was 'incr' which increments by the bottom of the stacks elements by a value. Although I got the basic test cases right, a few of them "timed out".

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
    def push(self, element):
        self.stack.append(element)
    def pop(self):
        if self.stack:
            self.stack.pop()
    def incr(self, num_elements, value):
        '''Increments bottom num_elements by value'''
        for idx in range(num_elements):
            self.stack[idx] += value
    def print_top(self):
        print(self.stack[-1])
```

I'm guessing my implementation was too slow. I'm not sure how to make it faster. I tried to replace the 'incr' with the following list comprension but it didn't make a significant difference when I timed it with a million elements.

```
[x + value for x in self.stack[:num_elements]].extend(self.stack[num_elements:])
```

So I'm not exactly sure why I got it wrong.. maybe it was due to the push and the pop?

Comment: Can you link to the original question?

Comment: It was a timed question for a company, I don't think I can view it anymore

Comment: Instead of incrementing every entry, perhaps keep a list of increments, and when you `pop()` apply pending increments. And this would probably be better on [codereview.se], I think.

Comment: I didn't even think of that.. maybe that's what it was

Comment: I'm quite surprised it timed out. What was the time limit?

Comment: I'm not sure what the time limit was. Hackerrank just showed me Test Case#1 passed, Test Case #2 passed, ... Test Case #7 Timed Out

Comment: Although if it was due to not keeping a list of pending increments, this would increase runtime of pop() since now I would be checking if there is a pending applied to that element each time

Comment: There was another question on SO about this same problem and they too could not pass all tests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001791/stack-operations-terminating-due-to-timeout

Comment: This actually looks like the exact same question. It looks like it was solved by initializing the maximum number to a numpy array and then using numpy

Comment: Could you post the hackerrank link ??